# Error in npm start

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am new to angular.
I am getting these err on "npm start"

```html
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.17134
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.14.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! missing script: start
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\lenovo\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Why is there no `package.json`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Double check the file `C:\Users\lenovo\package.json` exists and is readable. If yes, try again.

Comment: The directory from which you are trying to execute `npm start` should have `package.json` inside it.. In your case the `lenovo` directory should contain it..

Comment: now shows,npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.17134
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.14.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! missing script: start
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\lenovo\npm-debug.log

Comment: You shouldn't need to `npm init`. Do you already have an Angular project on that machine? If so, does it contain a file called `package.json`?

Comment: i have package.json at the path /lenovo . No, i don't have angular project on the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `package.json` don't have script `start`.

Example :

```
{
    "name: "my project",

    /* you should create scripts same here */
    "scripts":{
        "start": "node index.js"  /* index.js is file you want run */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your lenovo folder doesn't have package.json file

error said that

```
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> 'C:\Users\lenovo\package.json'
```

> [start your angular journey from here](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)